# CloudFoundry .cfignore file to exclude one of two JAR files

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

my Gradle build job creates two JAR files beneath build/libs folder (with changing VERSION placeholder):

```
$ ls build/libs
foo-VERSION.jar foo-VERSION-all.jar
```

ONLY the 'foo-VERSION-all.jar' represents an artifact to get uploaded to CloudFoundry instance via

```
$ cf push
```

My problem is that BOTH JAR files are uploaded to CloudFoundry instance resulting in error messages like

> No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've
>   pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line
>   argument or path manifest entry.

OK, -p CLI argument would be an option, but there should be another one!

In CloudFoundry's manifest.yml I declare a path:

```
$ grep path manifest.yml
  path: build/libs
```

Now it should be feasible to declare a .cfignore file (should be analogous to well-known .gitignore files) to exclude the foo-VERSION.jar file, but I don't get it, e.g. with the following attempt:

```
$ cat .cfignore
*
!build/libs/*-all.jar
```

What's wrong with that? Any idea to get it work?

Thanks

Christian

PS: I wanted to add a tag ".cfignore" to my post, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

By default the root of your app and the location from which files are pushed is `.`. When you set the `path` in your manifest.yml or set `cf push -p`, you're changing the root of your app.

In your example, you're changing the root to `build/libs`. Because of this you need to:

1. put `.cfignore` in the `build/libs` folder
2. use relative paths from `build/libs`.

The following worked for me, when put in `build/libs/.cfignore`:

```
*
!foo-*-all.jar
```

This ended up with only one JAR file being uploaded.

Other notes, make sure you're on a recent version. There have been some past [bugs reported in this area](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22cfignore%22+).

---

Probably also worth mentioning, it would make things a lot simpler if you adjusted your build to generate a file with a stable name, like `foo-push-me.jar`. If the name didn't change, you could set `path: build/libs/foo-push-me.jar` and you wouldn't need to mess with all the ignore files.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

thanks for clarification.
I'm sure you've guessed it, local folder ./build is the one created newly with every build (and removed with every clean build); for that reason I have never put this path under version control, which would be necessary.

So at first I took the workaround you've mentioned.

This solution doesn't convince me: I would expect to declare the artifact to upload in a file found in project's root path.

But I'm not getting this to work :-(

Christian

Comment: I didn't try this (or think of it at the time) but I think it would work if you put `.cfignore` in the root of your project but you set `path: .`. The cli would look for the `.cfignore` file in the root of where you push. You would just need to make sure that you ignore everything except the one JAR file you want to upload. I think your original `.cfignore` file should do that.